# Why doesnt my textbox clear the text after I set the text to string.Empty

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

So I have my `MainWindow` in which I've set a DataContext like so..

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

And The `MainViewModel` has a property called `Message`

```
class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
private string _message;

public string Message
{
    get { return _message; }
    set
    {
        _message = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

}
```

The `ObservableObject` is super straightforward

```
class ObservableObject
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The issue I'm facing is the binding of my `TextBox`.. As we can see here, I'm currently binding the `Text` property to `Message`

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Message, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
         VerticalAlignment="Center"
         Foreground="LightGray"
         BorderThickness="0"
         Margin="15,0,0,0"
         Width="600"
         TextWrapping="Wrap"
         x:Name="MessageBox">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Return"
                    Command="{Binding SendMessageCommand}"/>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

The Command

```
SendMessageCommand = new RelayCommand(o =>
{
    MessageBox.Show(Message);
    Message = string.Empty;
});
```

And the binding works great! The only issue is that when I set `Message` to `""` or `string.Empty` it doesn't actually reflect on the View.

Let's take this example, if I were to type in `"Hello"` into the `TextBox` and click `Enter` it would show a `MessageBox` with the text `"Hello"` and as we can see if we look at the command, I'm setting the `Message` property to `string.Empty` right after that but it doesn't update the `TextBox` text, it would still say `"Hello"`, which is strange because if I click enter again it shows an empty `MessageBox`

Why is that? Is this a bug?

Comment: When you type in TextBox, `OnPropertyChanged` has been call.
But in the RelayCommand, it is not.

Comment: @ArAui I tried calling `OnPropertyChanged();` after setting `Message = string.Empty` and that still didn't do anything, and it would call it either way because I'm calling it inside `set`

Comment: Sorry for my above comment it's not complete. I think it seems like virtual method cannot be called in lambda.

Comment: Did you look at the output window? Are there any exceptions?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I did yeah, no exceptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should implement the interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
class ObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Otherwise, your view can't subscribe to the event, which means that the view is never informed when the value of your property changes.

Comment: Wow.. I totally forgot that I needed to inherit from INPC, I just implemented the interface, thanks!

Comment: Sometimes, one doesn't see the forest because there are too many trees. You're welcome!